# Как реализовать сложение двух функций в Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

вот так выглядит код 2 степпер выполняющие свою функцию + 2 функции калькулятора для каждой из 2ух позиций и есть кнопка sell, по которой должны складываться кол-во 1 позиции умноженной на цену и колв-во 2 позиции умноженной на другую цену и появляться вместо строки Calculator. Заранее извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, это мой первый раз))]

[image: фото Xcode]

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете хранить значение степперов в переменных и использовать их в вычислениях. Вот так, например:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var guinessQuantity: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var heinekenQuantity: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myCalculatorOfBeer: UILabel!

    private var guinessQ = 0
    private var heinekenQ = 0

    @IBAction func guinessStepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        guinessQ = Int(sender.value)
        guinessQuantity.text = guinessQ.description
    }

    @IBAction func heinekenStepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        heinekenQ = Int(sender.value)
        heinekenQuantity.text = heinekenQ.description
    }

    @IBAction func sellButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let result = Double(guinessQ * 3) + (Double(heinekenQ) * 2.75)
        myCalculatorOfBeer.text = result.description
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


}
```